# Procedure to add history of an event to Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, procedure

I need to write a procedure in Oracle SQL that inserts data from three tables into one separate table without any keys. Here is the model of my database:

[image: Model]. (All of the column names are in Polish, sorry about that).

I have already created a table for history:

```
create table art_historia(
data_koncertu date default sysdate,   --Concert date
miejsce_koncertu varchar2(40),        --Place of concert
nazwa_zespolu varchar2(30),           --Name of band
liczba_widzow number(5),              --Number of viewers
bilans_finansowy number (8,2));       --Finance balance
```

And the values that I want to insert there using this procedure I can picture with this select:

```
select s.miasto, a.nazwa_zespolu, k.ilosc_sprzedanych_biletow, k.zysk
    from art_sala s, art_koncert k, art_artysta a
    where k.kod_sali_koncertowej = s.kod_sali_koncertowej and
    k.kod_artysty = a.kod_artysty and
    k.id_koncertu = (variable of concert id);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't see images right now. Though: it seems that you have a target table, you have source tables, you wrote a query ... so, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_ART_HIST_P (p_in_concert_id number) IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO art_historia
select s.miasto, a.nazwa_zespolu, k.ilosc_sprzedanych_biletow, k.zysk
    from art_sala s, art_koncert k, art_artysta a
    where k.kod_sali_koncertowej = s.kod_sali_koncertowej and
    k.kod_artysty = a.kod_artysty and
    k.id_koncertu = p_in_concert_id;
END;
```

Comment: There is an error 

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
3/13      PL/SQL: ORA-00947: niewystarczająca liczba wartości
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: hmm is because the select needs to have 5 values because the table has 5 columns.  Either return 5 values on the query or define 4 values to be inserted by using INSERT INTO art_historia (column1,column2,column3). Sorry I can't fix that because of the polish names